# Pivot wider with selective columns in R

Tags: r

I am grouping the dataframe by ID and qual and want to pivot table to add mothers and fathers name and age to new columns but the code below doesn't achieve what i'm trying to do.
Below is my dataframe:

```
mydata<-
    ID  name    age qual    school  relation
    A123    Bob 10  p   a   child
    A123    Alice   35  p   b   mother
    A123    dani    40  q   c   father
    A125    Tom 8   q   a   child
    A125    Maria   30  q   a   mother
    A125    jack    32  p   a   father
    A129    cook    14  p   d   child
    A129    Victoria    45  p   d   mother
```

Desired output as below:

```
ID  name    age qual    school  relation    mom_name    mom_age father_name father_age
A123    Bob 10  p   a   child   Alice   35  dani    40
A123    Alice   35  p   b   mother  NA  NA  NA  NA
A123    dani    40  p   c   father  NA  NA  NA  NA
A125    Tom 8   q   a   child   Maria   30  NA  NA
A125    Maria   30  q   a   mother  NA  NA  NA  NA
A125    jack    32  p   a   father  NA  NA  NA  NA
A129    cook    14  p   d   child   Victoria    45  NA  NA
A129    Victoria    45  p   d   mother  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

My code:

```
mydata_result <- mydata %>%
+   group_by(ID, qual) %>%
+   mutate(
+     moms_name = ifelse(relation == "mother", name, "NA"),
+     moms_age = ifelse(relation == "mother", age, "NA"),
+     fathers_name = ifelse(relation == "father", name, "NA"),
+     fathers_age = ifelse(relation == "father", age, "NA")
+   ) %>%
+   fill(moms_name, moms_age, fathers_name, fathers_age, .direction = "down")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mydata %>%
   left_join(pivot_wider(.,id_cols = ID, names_from = relation, 
                 values_from = c(name, age),
                 names_vary = 'slowest'), 
             c('ID', name = 'name_child'))

    ID     name age qual school relation age_child name_mother age_mother name_father age_father
1 A123      Bob  10    p      a    child        10       Alice         35        dani         40
2 A123    Alice  35    p      b   mother        NA        <NA>         NA        <NA>         NA
3 A123     dani  40    q      c   father        NA        <NA>         NA        <NA>         NA
4 A125      Tom   8    q      a    child         8       Maria         30        jack         32
5 A125    Maria  30    q      a   mother        NA        <NA>         NA        <NA>         NA
6 A125     jack  32    p      a   father        NA        <NA>         NA        <NA>         NA
7 A129     cook  14    p      d    child        14    Victoria         45        <NA>         NA
8 A129 Victoria  45    p      d   mother        NA        <NA>         NA        <NA>         NA
```

Comment: what if we want to group data by ID and qual instead?

Comment: @akang include that in the `id_cols` ie `id_cols = c(ID, qual)`